# Swift: Problems with UILabels and UIButtons

Tags: swift, uibutton, uialertcontroller

I have a few strange things happening with my interface.

First of all, when I load the VC, the labels appear in the wrong color. I've set them correctly in the IB and also in the code, for good measure.

Next, a few problems with buttons. I'm working on a simple scoreboard app where you touch a player's score and it loads an alert to update their score. The scores array is updated correctly, as can be seen when debugging, but the display of the score doesn't quite work. Here are the problems:

1. The label text is cut off. The start of the text is visible but most of the right side is cut off so usually only one digit will show, or one digit plus a tiny part of the next digit. In the IB, the button is definitely wide enough to display several digits. The button is in a stack view with the player's name and they're set to equal widths. (both players, each a name label and a score button, are then embedded in another stack view).
   Upon further investigation (replacing the default text of the button from "0" to "???" there seems to be an alignment problem. With default text of ???, entering 100 as the score for one player shows "..." for player 1 and 0 for player 2, with those two things being left-justified. I don't see any spot in the IB to justify the text of a button but the control itself is center-aligned.
2. When either score is clicked, in the moment before the alert pops up to enter the score, I can see that both score seem to bulge out, which sometimes results in the number being replaced by an ellipses (which I guess suggests that the text size is changing but not the view's size. In this moment,
3. Sometimes the scores are reset. Or appear to be reset.
4. Also, when I enter a new score, there's about a second after the alert disappears where the buttons display their default text, before changing to display the score (which, with the default text set to "???" is always simply shrunk/truncated to an ellipsis.

Pretty weird. Here's my code.

```
var playerScores =  [[Int](), [Int]()]  // Outer array is players, inner array is rounds
    { didSet {
        if let scores = scoreViews {
            for (index, playerScore) in scores.enumerated() {
                // Setting it here works, but the text is still truncated,
                playerScore.titleLabel?.text = String(describing: totalScore(index))
            }
        }
    }
}

func totalScore(_ player: Int) -> Int {
    return playerScores[player].reduce(0, +)
}

private func scoreEntryAlertFor(player: Int) -> UIAlertController {
    // Create the alert controller
    let updateScoreAlert = UIAlertController(title: ScoreAlertStrings.title,
                                             message: ScoreAlertStrings.message + playerNames[player],
                                             preferredStyle: .alert)
    // Add the text field for score
    updateScoreAlert.addTextField { (textField) in textField.keyboardType = .numberPad }

    // Configure the buttons for add and subtract
    let addScore = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default) { (_) in
        self.updateScoreFor(player: player, from: updateScoreAlert)
    }

    let subtractScore = UIAlertAction(title: "Subtract", style: .default) { (_) in
        self.updateScoreFor(player: player, from: updateScoreAlert, subtract: true)
    }

    // Add the buttons
    updateScoreAlert.addAction(addScore); updateScoreAlert.addAction(subtractScore)
    updateScoreAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

    return updateScoreAlert
}

private func updateScoreFor(player: Int, from alert: UIAlertController, subtract: Bool = false) {
        if let newScoreText = alert.textFields?.last?.text {
            if let newScore = Int(newScoreText) {
                playerScores[player].append(subtract ? -newScore: newScore)
            }
        }
    }

@IBAction func playerScoreTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let playerNumber = sender.tag
    let updateAlert = scoreEntryAlertFor(player: playerNumber)
    present(updateAlert, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: screenshots please?

Comment: Questions are received best when you focus on *one* issue at a time. You may want to break this into four (or five) separate questions.